# Why is it unlikely one needs to use the tollways when riding a taxi after midnight, early hours of the morning or a weekend in Bangkok?

Tags: thailand, taxis, fares, bangkok

From https://itsbetterinthailand.com/how-to-use-local-taxis-in-bangkok-without-getting-ripped-off-or-lost/ ([mirror 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20200614203404/https://itsbetterinthailand.com/how-to-use-local-taxis-in-bangkok-without-getting-ripped-off-or-lost/),  [mirror 2](http://archive.is/A4YZj)):

> If it’s after midnight, early hours of the morning or a weekend, it’s likely you don’t need to use the tollways.

Why is it unlikely one needs to use the tollways when riding a taxi after midnight, early hours of the morning or a weekend in Bangkok?

E.g. is that because there is less traffic at these times and subsequently the use of the roads with tollways is less interesting, or is that because there is fewer roads with active tollways at these times?

Comment: AFAIK all.tollways in Thailand have fixed tolls and operate 24/7.

Comment: @lambshaanxy thanks for the information! You're welcome to convert the comment into an answer, to remove one possible explanation.

Comment: While not an absolute requiment here, some advance research is expected and this question does not show any.

Comment: @Willeke Some information isn't easy to find in English, e.g. whether tollways in Thailand have fixed tolls and operate 24/7. I've read several guides on using taxi in Bangkok, including the one I mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 4):

From the same article, under 'Traffic':

> If you’re traveling after midnight, traffic is usually much lighter

implying that using the tollways won't gain you anything at that time.